# Oracle SQL: Constraint foreign key with multiple values from same column: duplicate column name error

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I want to create a battle table referencing to 2 players.

```
CREATE TABLE Battle
(
    player_1            NUMBER(10),
    player_2            NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Battle PRIMARY KEY(player_1, player_2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Battle_Player FOREIGN KEY(player_1, player_2) REFERENCES Player(id, id)
);
```

But appearantly I can't have duplicate column names, I've tried "Player(id)" as well but it doesn't work either, any idea?

```
SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name
00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create two different foreign keys since you are not referencing the same row in the parent table, but two independent rows.

Something like -

```
CREATE TABLE Battle
(
    player_1            NUMBER(10),
    player_2            NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Battle PRIMARY KEY(player_1, player_2),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Battle_Player1 FOREIGN KEY player_1 REFERENCES Player(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Battle_Player2 FOREIGN KEY player_2 REFERENCES Player(id)
);
```